# .Net Core Get Number Of Concurrent Connections

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, asp.net-core

Is there any way to get or calculate number of currently connected clients in .Net Core (1.1 and 2.0)? Website is running on Nginx on Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Over http? Unless you are using something like SignalR, you will need to specify what you mean by "connected". Otherwise the answer will always be 0, or maybe 42 :)

Comment: Yes, http. Let's say I want to check how many requests are in processing right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Stub Status Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html) which gives you a nginx endpoint that returns basic status including:

`Active connections`
The current number of active client connections including Waiting connections.

Now, this is just one interpretation of connections. This would not be how many are using the system over a period of time but how many http requests are currently active.